# Move text to top of the td

Tags: html, css

How can I move the text to the top corner of a `<td>` ?. I have tried like this but this doesnt work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NPea.jpg)

```css
.cssprop
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="cssprop">
    14.
    </td>
    <td>
    some very long text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is already at the top in your example. Add `td {height: 50px}` and you will see

Comment: try `vertical-align: top` instead

Comment: tried both, not working for me!!

Comment: Replace "14." by <div style="top: -4px;position: relative;">14.</div>

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="cssprop">
    14.
    </td>
    <td>
    some very long text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
.cssprop
{
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 200px !important;
}
</style>
```

The CSS height was changed to exaggerate the display result.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/md2100/74stpf0p/